# Parallax Scrolling effect isn't working - HTML CSS only

Tags: html, css, parallax

I'm trying to learn how to do parallax scrolling effect, watched some tutorials and tried one, but it's not working, any idea what might be wrong?

what shows is just static pictures, it doesn't have any parallax effect at all.

and I can't upload this post because it says my post is mostly code, i wish i can add some lorem here because i literally have no idea what kind of information to add more...

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <title>Task 3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parallax-wrapper">
      <div class="single-parallax parallax parallax-bg-1">
        <h1>Parallax One</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="single-parallax static-bg">
        <h1>No Parallax</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="single-parallax parallax parallax-bg-2">
        <h1>Parallax One</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE :

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parallax-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 2px;
}

.single-parallax {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.single-parallax h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.parallax::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.parallax-bg-1::after {
  background-image: url(../imgs/1.png);
}
.parallax-bg-2::after {
  background-image: url(../imgs/2.png);
}

.static-bg {
  background: greenyellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there! You shouldn't add the `background-image` to `::after`, you can just add it to the element itself. And you forget a few lines of code for the `background-image`:

```css
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
```

Here it is all together:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.parallax-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    perspective: 2px;
}
  
.single-parallax {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
  
.single-parallax h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
  
.parallax-bg-1 {
    background-image: url(../imgs/1.png);
}
.parallax-bg-2 {
    background-image: url(../imgs/2.png);
}
  
.static-bg {
    background: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax-wrapper">
    <div class="single-parallax parallax parallax-bg-1">
      <h1>Parallax One</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="single-parallax static-bg">
      <h1>No Parallax</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="single-parallax parallax parallax-bg-2">
      <h1>Parallax One</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to have the little scroll effect on the `background-image`, you can use `::after` just like you did:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.parallax-wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 2px;
}
.single-parallax{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.single-parallax h1{
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.parallax::after{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.parallax-bg-1::after{
  background-image: url(../imgs/1.png);
}
.parallax-bg-2::after{
  background-image: url(../imgs/2.png);
}
.static-bg{
  background: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
  <div class="parallax-wrapper">
    <div class="single-parallax parallax parallax-bg-1">
      <h1>Parallax One</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="single-parallax static-bg">
      <h1>No Parallax</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="single-parallax parallax parallax-bg-2">
      <h1>Parallax One</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is definitely much better, but if you can help me with 1 more thing, the pictures themselves aren't moving when I scroll down, I think this has to be about the translateZ, scale, and the perspective in the CSS, here is the video I'm trying to do, check out minute 9:06  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIJAyGpJohE&list=LL&index=2&ab_channel=TryCode

Comment: Then you would use the `::after` to add the `background-image`, let me add it to the code above!